# How to launch Vivado on Ubuntu?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-18.04, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed Xilinx Vivado 2019.1.

Installation went fine and I installed it in the home/Desktop directory instead of the usual opt/Xilinx directory. I want to know how can I launch it now that I have installed it. This are the files I have on `Desktop/Xilinx`:

```
DocNav
Downloads
sdk
Vivado
xic
'Documentation Navigator.desktop'
'Vivado 2019.1.desktop'
'Vivado HLS 2019.1.desktop'
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

you have to source the environment in a terminal then launch vivado.

```
$ source /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2017.2/settings64.sh
$ vivado&
```

Adapt the path accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

PS: It's also necessary to have the `libtinfo5` package installed to start vivado

Comment: It was the issue in my case. Vivado was complaining about librdi_commontasks.so not being found and I couldn't find it.